# Karma cannot start Firefox

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner

I use grunt-karma to run Firefox. But displayed below error:

```
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Firefox
    CreateProcessW: [][][][][][][].[][][][]
INFO [launcher]: Try to start Firefox again.
Fatal error: EPERM, open 'C:\Users\Txxx~1\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-99662615\prefs.js'
```

[] means square character which should be a unreadable code and may be Chinese words.

I'm sure that I installed karma-firefox-launcher into globle and local.

And I can run the Chrome in the same way.

How can I resolve the error and run the Firefox ?

version info:

```
nodejs 0.8.7
grunt 0.4.1
karma 0.10.2
karma-grunt 0.6.2
karma-firefox-launcher 0.1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated Nodejs to 0.10.1 and solved it.